# Why does Transform-style: preserve-3d break z-zindex?

Tags: html, css

Why does Transform-style: preserve-3d break z-zindex?

I am experimenting with CSS 3d effects:
My Goal is to create a 3-dimensional animated letter.
As soon as I add transform-style: preserve-3d to #F_cnt the divs appear in the wrong layers. The z-index has no effect. 
When I remove transform-style: preserve-3d it works fine.
Please help me! Thank you!

```css
#F1 {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 25rem;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateZ(5rem);
}

#F2 {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5rem;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateZ(5rem);
}

#F3 {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateZ(5rem);
  left: 5rem;
  top: 10rem;
}

#Fb1 {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 25rem;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(2.5rem, -2.5rem, 4.99rem);
}

#Fb2 {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5rem;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate3d(2.5rem, -2.5rem, 4.99rem)
}

#Fb3 {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5rem;
  top: 10rem;
  transform: translate3d(2.5rem, -2.5rem, 4.99rem)
}

#Ftop_1 {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) skewX(-27deg) translateZ(5rem);
}

#Ftop_2 {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10rem;
  left: 5rem;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) skewX(-27deg) translateZ(5rem);
}

#Fbot {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25rem;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) skewX(-27deg) translateZ(4.99rem);
}

#Fbot_2 {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15rem;
  left: 5rem;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) skewX(-27deg) translateZ(4.99rem);
}

#Fbot_3 {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5rem;
  left: 5rem;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) skewX(-27deg) translateZ(4.99rem);
}

#Fright_1 {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15rem;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotateY(-59deg) skewY(-26.8deg) translateZ(5rem);
}

#Fright_2 {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10rem;
  left: 5rem;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotateY(-59deg) skewY(-26.8deg) translateZ(5rem);
}

#Fright_3 {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25rem;
  left: 5rem;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotateY(-59deg) skewY(-26.8deg) translateZ(5rem);
}

#Fright_4 {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15rem;
  left: 10rem;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotateY(-59deg) skewY(-26.8deg) translateZ(5rem);
}

#Fleft {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 25rem;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25rem;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotateY(-59deg) skewY(-26.8deg) translateZ(4.99rem);
}

#F_cnt {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-left: 30rem;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: F-anim;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#F {
  perspective: 10000px;
  perspective-origin: 50%;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="F">
    <div id="F_cnt">
      <div id="F1"></div>
      <div id="F2"></div>
      <div id="F3"></div>
      <div id="Fb1"></div>
      <div id="Fb2"></div>
      <div id="Fb3"></div>
      <div id="Ftop_1"></div>
      <div id="Ftop_2"></div>
      <div id="Fbot"></div>
      <div id="Fbot_2"></div>
      <div id="Fbot_3"></div>
      <div id="Fright_1"></div>
      <div id="Fright_2"></div>
      <div id="Fright_3"></div>
      <div id="Fright_4"></div>
      <div id="Fleft"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: share you full code

Comment: I added the full html and css code!

Comment: That's because when you use 3D transform it creates a new stacking context. Technically using 3D transform will offload the rendering to the GPU and it paints it on top of the document, thereby negating the z-index property. Therefore, the best way is to simply use translateZ to affect the stacking of elements along the z-axis for all the elements instead of relying on z-indeces.

Comment: I updated the Code with translateZ, but it still doesn't work! Only the yellow and the blue layer is now correct... Please help me! Thank you!